# Append a cell in a HTML table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, append, cell

I have a table in my web page, just this code:

```
<table id = "grid" >
</table>
```

Also, this button to add three columns in one row (the elements are a: text area, a droppable area and a button).

```
<button class = "plus"> + </button>
```

this function is run when the button is clicked:

```
$( ".plus" ).button().click(function() {
   $('<tr></tr>').appendTo("#grid");
   $('<td><textarea/></td>').appendTo("#grid tr:last"); 
   $('<td id = "regla"></td>').droppable( drpOptions ).appendTo("#grid tr:last");
   $('<td><button class = "addRow"> + </button></td>').appendTo("#grid tr:last");
});
```

This runs smoothly, up to this point all good. The thing I can't make is that when the button I'm appending (class="addRow") is clicked the button is removed and the same set of three items (text area, droppable and the button) is append to the row. I want that this new button appended do the same thing.

I think that the code is going to look like this:

```
$(".addRow").button().click(function(){
  var myColumn = $(this).closest("td").prevAll("td").length;
  var myRow = $(this).closest("tr").prevAll("tr").length;
  $("#grid").rows[myRow].cells[myColumn].append('<td><textarea/></td>');
});
```

or like this:

```
$(this).parents("table").find("tr:eq("+myRow+")")(function(){
 $(this).find("td:eq("+myColumn+")").append('<td><textarea/></td>');
});
```

Can you help me make it right or do it the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came across trying to do this myself and ended up with an equivalent to this:

```
$( ".plus" ).button().click(function() {
   addRow();
});

function addRow() {
   var newRow = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo($('#grid'));
   addRowContents(newRow);
}

function addRowAfter(target) {
  var newRow = $('<tr></tr>');
  addRowContents(newRow);
  target.after(newRow);
}

function addRowContents(row) {
 $('<td><textarea/></td>').appendTo(row); 
   $('<td id = "regla"></td>').droppable( drpOptions ).appendTo(row);
  var buttonCell = $('<td></td>').appendTo(row);
  $('<button></button>').addClass('addRow').text('+').click(function(){
    addRowAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
    $(this).hide();
  }).appendTo(buttonCell); 
}
```

I believe this is what you were after, the plus button adds a new row to the end of the table, and the button on each row adds a new row directly after that row, and then hides the button. If you paste that code into your fiddle it should work.

Bit late but thought I'd post just in case it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for posting, it is the solution. I went around the problem, you may find it useful too, I worked all layout in twitter boostrap (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

As your new button `#addrow` is created dynamically, so directe event binding won't work here, you need to delegate the event to the existing one like the table `#grid`. You need to create a `var addBtn = $(".addRow").button();` and use this var in the event delegation with `.on()` handler:

```
var addBtn = $(".addRow").button();

$("#grid").on('click', addBtn, function(){
   var myColumn = $(this).closest("td").prevAll("td").length;
   var myRow = $(this).closest("tr").prevAll("tr").length;
   $("#grid").rows[myRow].cells[myColumn].append('<td><textarea/></td>');
});
```

Comment: Jai, thanks for you answer, it sounds just right, but I can't get it running. I put the code in JS Bin (http://jsbin.com/ihakim/1/edit). Would you be able to check what is happening and make it work?